# Is it possible to un-plant bush beans planted in error?

Tags: soil, seeds, green-beans

I re-seeded my pole beans yesterday, after soaking the seeds.  Today I discovered I had confused the bush bean packet with the pole bean packet, and what I actually planted yesterday, along the edges of a four-pole teepee, was the bush bean seeds.  Do I have to wait until they come up before pulling them out?  (The whole point of the thing was that I had an itch to try my hand at pole beans for the first time.)

The soil is quite heavy (high clay content), and we've had a lot of rain lately.  I wonder if trying to find them will be like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Other options that occur to me:

- plant the real pole beans in the same place, and let them co-exist
- wait a week and then plant the real pole beans in the same place, with the idea of transplanting the bush bean seedlings to the other location, since they'll presumably germinate first

Comment: Co-existence solution sounds good, depending on density of seed sowing. Thin as seems reasonable after they are both established. Cutting of the short bush types at ground level will result in less root disturbance.

Comment: @ColinBeckingham - Thanks.  I was able to find them and get them out again.  The root was unemerged in a couple of them, but was about half an inch long or less in the others.  I put them between damp paper towels overnight and will plant them in the other location today.  I'll comment again as to whether they survived the transplanting and made seed leaves.

Comment: @aparente001 Did your transplants survive?

Comment: yes.............